# A better way to aggregate data and keep table structure and column names with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataset like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':['a','a','b','b'], 'x2':[True, True, True, False], 'x3':[1,1,1,1]})
df
  x1     x2  x3
0  a   True   1
1  a   True   1
2  b   True   1
3  b  False   1
```

I often want to perform a groupby-aggregate operation where I group by multiple columns and apply multiple functions to one column. Furthermore, I usually don't want a multi-indexed, multi-level table.  To accomplish this, it's taking me three lines of code which seems excessive.

For example

```
bg = df.groupby(['x1', 'x2']).agg({'x3': {'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean}})
bg.columns = bg.columns.droplevel(0)
bg.reset_index()
```

Is there a better way?  Not to gripe, but I'm coming from an R/data.table background where something like this is a nice one-liner like

```
df[, list(my_sum=sum(x3), my_mean=mean(x3)), by=list(x1, x2)]
```

Comment: you can avoid the `reset_index` by calling `groupby` with `as_index=False`

Comment: i agree with you that the bias in pandas towards multi-indexes is pretty annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use @Happy01 answer but instead of `as_index=False` you could add `reset_index` to the end:

```
In [1331]: df.groupby(['x1', 'x2'])['x3'].agg( {'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean}).reset_index()
Out[1331]: 
  x1     x2  my_mean  my_sum
0  a   True        1       2
1  b  False        1       1
2  b   True        1       1
```

**Benchmarking**, for `reset_index` it works faster:

```
In [1333]: %timeit df.groupby(['x1', 'x2'], as_index=False)['x3'].agg({'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean})
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop

In [1334]: %timeit df.groupby(['x1', 'x2'])['x3'].agg( {'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean}).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.82 ms per loop
```

You could do the same as your solution but with one line. Transpose your dataframe then do `reset_index` to drop your `x3` column or level 0, then transposing back and do `reset_index` again to achieve your desired output:

```
In [1374]: df.groupby(['x1', 'x2']).agg({'x3': {'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean}}).T.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).T.reset_index()
Out[1374]: 
  x1     x2  my_mean  my_sum
0  a   True        1       2
1  b  False        1       1
2  b   True        1       1
```

But it works slower:

```
In [1375]: %timeit df.groupby(['x1', 'x2']).agg({'x3': {'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean}}).T.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).T.reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.13 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice writeup.  But see my comment under Happy's answer.  This method also does not generalize well, I think.

Comment: Could you provide example for that case? Because I think last method drop level, not only column by name: `reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Comment: Bingo. The last method (while slowish and fairly cryptic) generalizes the best.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
In [81]: bg = df.groupby(['x1', 'x2'], as_index=False)['x3'].agg({'my_sum':np.sum, 'my_mean':np.mean})

In [82]: print bg
  x1     x2  my_sum  my_mean
0  a   True       2        1
1  b  False       1        1
2  b   True       1        1
```

Comment: This is nice.  Does it generalize, say if `df` had another column "x4" for which I wanted to calculate the mean?  I'm worried this solution only works because I gave an overly simple example that involves aggregation on one column, namely x3.

Comment: I agree that this works only when only one column is involved. But in the case that you also need, say, mean of x4, then you may want to keep the column level (i.e., them mean is for x3/x4).